# react native : why my screen's param(props) can't be passed while using stack navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

App.js

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
          <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Report" component={ReportScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

./screens/ReportScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import ReportReason from '../components/ReportReason';

const ReportScreen = ({route}) => {
    
    const textVal = '';
    if (route.param.title.length > 12){
        textVal = route.params.title.substring(0,10) + '...';
    }
    else {
        textVal = route.params.title;
    }
    
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style = {reportStyles.container}>
            <View style = {reportStyles.card}>
                <Text>Report</Text>
                <Text>{textval}</Text>
                <ReportReason/>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
```

part of ./components/ReportMension.js

```
const ReportMension = ({mension}) => {

return(

TouchableOpacity style={postModalStyles.listButton} onPress={()=>{
console.log(mension)
navigation.navigate('Report', { title: mension.title });
}}>
            <Text style={postModalStyles.text}>report</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

);
}
```

this is component of screen named Main.

console.log is operated normally.
why my component and navigator are cannot passed params(props)?
how to pass props when using stack navigaor??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in ReportMention, you can't reassign a `const` variable. Instead, try

```js
    let textVal = '';
    if (route.params.title.length > 12) {
        textVal = route.params.title.substring(0,10) + '...';
    }
    else {
        textVal = route.params.title;
    }
```

Or

```
const textVal = route.params.title.length > 12
  ? route.params.title.substring(0,10) + '...'
  : route.params.title;
```

Second, there's a typo in the condition: `route.param.title.length` should be `route.params.title.length`.  This would throw an error, since you can't access the property `length` on an object that is undefined.

These two syntax errors should prevent fast refresh from working, since the result wouldn't compile. If you fix these, and console.log the `route` object in ReportMention, you should get the params you're looking for.